# Is it possible to use a previously defined value in subsequent definitions of a `Block`?

Tags: scoping, variable-definitions, hold

Is it possible to use a previously defined value in subsequent definitions of a `Block`?

According to syntax coloration, this *should* work as expected, that is, returning both the data list and its length:

```
Clear["data", "len"]
Block[{ 
    data = Range[5],
    len = Length[data]
  },{len, data}
]
```

However, the result is:

> ```
> {0,{1,2,3,4,5}}
> ```

[image]

Surprisingly enough, this *works*:

```
Clear["data", "sum"]
echo = Block[{ 
   data = Range[5],
   sum = Plus[data, 1]
   }, {sum, data}
  ]
```

Producing:

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
> ```

Two questions:

- Why is `Length` unable to see the definition of `data`--whereas `Plus` seems to have no trouble with that?
- Most importantly, how can I ensure any given expression will make use of the proper `data` value?

FWIW, I *suspect* this should have to do with `Block` variables not being available immediately (as opposed to [`letrec` construct commonly found in functional language](https://ds26gte.github.io/tyscheme/index-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_6.1)). If I'm right this could be fixed using `Hold*`-related functions. But I was unable to find a solution by myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values of the variables in a [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) are set at definition time, when `data` has no value:

```
Clear["data","len"]
TracePrint[
    Block[
        {
        data=Range[5],
        len=Length[data]
        },
        {len,data}
    ],
    _Length
]
```

Length[data]

> {0, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

The difference between using [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) and [`Length`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length) is that when `data` has no value `data + 1` just evaluates to `data + 1` while `Length[data]` evaluates to 0. So, the `sum` variable still has `data` in it, and it's value can change when `data` acquires a value.

One possibility to achieve your goal is to use [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) instead of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) in your [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block):

```
Block[
    {
    data = Range[5],
    len := Length[data]
    },
    {len,data}
]
```

> {5, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

Another, more robust possibility is to use the currently undocumented `varargs` [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With) syntax:

```
With[
    {data = Range[5]},
    {len = Length[data]},

    {len, data}
]
```

> {5, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

Support for this syntax is not going away, and I believe the syntax should soon become documented.

Comment: As always, @Carl, thank you for this enlightening answer. Speaking about the documentation, I didn't remember from reading the [`Block` reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block?view=all)  that we can actually use delayed affectation. Good to know!!

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use `Block` with normal assignment, but you have to wait until `data` is available. (See the answer of @CarlWoll for the use of delayed assignment.)

```
Block[{data = Range@5, len},
 len = Length@data;
 {len, data}
 ]
```

However in this particular example, it is unclear why `Module` would not be preferable. Imo, `Block` should only be used when dynamic scoping is really needed, which is seldom.

Comment: Thanks, @Alan. The example given in the question is just a minimal example and certainly not my real use case. However, could you elaborate a little about the reason why `Module` would _generally_ be preferable to `Block`? I'm new to Mathematica, and it is not always obvious to choose between `With`, `Module` and `Block`.

Comment: @Sylvain take a look at this: [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution using [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) and [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html). But I wouldn't swear this is an optimal one:

```
Clear["data", "len", "sum"]
echo = Block[{ 
   data = Range[5],
   len = Hold[Length[ data]],
   sum = Hold[Plus[data, 1]]
   }, ReleaseHold[{len, sum, data}]
  ]
```

> ```
> {5, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
> ```

I can't really answer the *why* question though since none of the `Plus` or `Length` functions have the `Hold*` attribute defined:

```
Attributes[Plus]
Attributes[Length]
```

> ```
> {Flat, Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected}
> {Protected}
> ```

Comment: We could achieve the same effect using `Block[{data = Range[5], len := Length[data]}, {len, data}]`.  But a more conventional solution would be to avoid the deferred execution using the somewhat repetitive but idiomatic `Block[{data, len}, data = Range[5]; len = Length[data]; {len, data}]`.  Incidentally, `Block` is the analog to Scheme's [fluid-let](https://ds26gte.github.io/tyscheme/index-Z-H-7.html#node_sec_5.2) so the sequencing issue is not as likely to arise for `Block` as it would if instead we were using `Module` (= Scheme's `let`).

Comment: As I said in a comment to Carl's answer above, I completely missed the fact we can use _delayed_ affectation :/ Anyhow, thanks for the comment @WR, and for mentioning the "idiomatic" way of solving the issue!